# How can I change the background image with a JS function?

Tags: image, background, swap

I need to change the background image of a div using an onhover function.

I have tried several iterations of "document.getElementByID" without success

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.

    </div>

    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = 
"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" 
onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

  </body>
</html>
```

Following is the latest function I tried:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
  document.getElementById("image").body.backgroundImage = 
"url('img_bacon.jpg')";
```

I am expecting the div to include the background image but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .innerhtml and pass in whatever you want the body to be.

```
document.getElementById("image").innerhtml = "<div>CONTENT HERE</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(someimage.jpg)";`

You could consider using jquery.. then it would look something like this:

`$('#image').css("background-image", "url(someimage.jpg)");`